# debugging related errors in c# code which reads textfiles from server

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to read 100s of textfiles. Theyre located in  a directory which has about 15 folders and in those folders there are a number of textfiles. So the program should Loop through each folder and then loop through each file. Some nice users helped me come up with the code to do this, but I'm getting a number of errors and *they all seem to be related.*

The errors are numbered and marked as comments. I need help with applying the fix to each of them (new programmer so there are probably very obvious fixes to these which I probably overlooked).

```
   private static void ReadAllFilesStartingFromDirectory(string // 1) Identifyer expected "@\\camis01srfs04\DATA\Stats Analysis Project\Sobeys Stats\Atlantic")
          {

              const string searchPattern = "*.txt";
              string subDirectories = Directory.EnumerateDirectories( @"\camis01srfs04\DATA\Stats Analysis Project\Sobeys Stats\Atlantic");
              // 2) cannot implicity convert systems.collections.generic.ieenumerable<string> to 'string'
              string filesInDirectory = Directory.EnumerateFiles(//topLevelDirectory, searchPattern);


              foreach (string subDirectory in subDirectories) // 3) windowsformapplication.form1.subdirectories is a 'field' but is used like a 'type';
              {

                  ReadAllFilesStartingFromDirectory  (subDirectory);
                  // 4)  method must have return type
              }

              IterateFiles(filesInDirectory, topLevelDirectory);
              // 5) A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods
          }


          private static void IterateFiles(IEnumerable<string> files, string directory)
          {
              int counter = 0;
              foreach (var file in files)
              {


                     // string[] filelines = File.ReadAllLines(file) and execute code;




              }
          }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, lets try to tackle your issues one by one, before proposing a slightly different solution to your problem.

1) Identifyer expected "@\camis01srfs04\DATA\Stats Analysis Project\Sobeystats\Atlantic")

```
static void ReadAllFilesStartingFromDirectory(string )
```

You will need to provide a name for the arguments to a method, as in:

```
static void ReadAllFilesStartingFromDirectory(string topLevelDirectory)
```

2) cannot implicity convert systems.collections.generic.ieenumerable to 'string'

```
string subDirectories = Directory.EnumerateDirectories( @"\camis01srfs04\DATA\Stats Analysis Project\Sobeys Stats\Atlantic");
```

The return value of `Directory.EnumerateDirectories` is `IEnumerable<string>`, not `string`. You can change this code to one of the two lines below:

```
IEnumerable<string> subDirectories = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(topLevelDirectory);
var subDirectories = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(topLevelDirectory);
```

The same is true for this line (it returns an `IEnumerable<string>`):

```
string filesInDirectory = Directory.EnumerateFiles(//topLevelDirectory, searchPattern);
```

We can change it to

```
var filesInDirectory = Directory.EnumerateFiles(topLevelDirectory, searchPattern);
```

3) windowsformapplication.form1.subdirectories is a 'field' but is used like a 'type';

This error message should be gone now with the changes we have made in 2)

4)  method must have return type

This error message should also be gone now with the changes we have made in 2)

5) A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods

This error message should also be gone now with the changes we have made in 2)

So this would make your program, with the corrections we just made look like this:

```
private static void ReadAllFilesStartingFromDirectory(string topLevelDirectory)
{
    const string searchPattern = "*.txt";
    var subDirectories = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(topLevelDirectory);

    foreach (string subDirectory in subDirectories) 
        ReadAllFilesStartingFromDirectory(subDirectory);

    var filesInDirectory = Directory.EnumerateFiles(topLevelDirectory, searchPattern);
    IterateFiles(filesInDirectory, topLevelDirectory);
}

private static void IterateFiles(IEnumerable<string> files, string directory)
{
    int counter = 0;
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        var filelines = File.ReadAllLines(file) 
        //and execute code;
    }
}
```

The method `Directory.EnumerateFiles` already supports searching subdirectories recursively, so you could also do this:

```
public static void ProcessAllFilesUnderDirectory(string topLevelDirectory, string searchMask, Action<string> processFile)
{
    var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(topLevelDirectory, searchMask, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    foreach (var file in files)
        processFile(file);
}
private static void ProcessAFile(string fileName)
{
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
    // perform processing.
}

public static void Main(params string[] args)
{
    ProcessAllFilesUnderDirectory(@"\camis01srfs04\DATA\Stats Analysis Project\Sobeys Stats\Atlantic", "*.txt", ProcessAFile);
}
```

Comment: Excellent response. Does it matter if I make the files variable of datatype string? Also you're calling the method processFile(file) but the method's actual name is ProcessAFile, that's just a typo right? Also, So I use the main method to call ProcessAllFilesUnderDirectory to search through each folder. In that method I call processAfile method to search each file. If this is the case, shouldn't main be placed above the other 2 methods and not below.

Comment: @Newuser the `var` notation is one that you can use when the compiler can determine the type itself. In this case the `var file` on line 4 is indeed `string file`. `processFile` is not a typo. If you look at the third argument of the method `ProcessAllFilesUnderDirectory` you will notice it is named `processFile` and is of the type `Action<string>`, which will match any method that has the signature `void MethodName(string argumentName)`. The `ProcessAFile` method matches this signature, so we can provide "a pointer" to that method when we call `ProcessAllFilesUnderDirectory` in `Main`.

Comment: @Newuser in c#, the order in which you declare methods is not important. The compiler will figure this out.

Comment: So what I'm doing now is that I'm simply exporting all of my processing code to the ProcessAFile method. However, I'm getting numerous errors which say all my variables do not exist in the current context. This is strange because I also included them all in the ProcessAfile method. Can I contact you through chat or email? The code is too much for me to paste on the comments section. I'm quite baffled as to why my variables aren't being recognized even though they are declared.

Comment: @Newuser Perhaps you could paste your code in a gist: https://gist.github.com/ so I can have a look at it.

Comment: here is the original code with no changes: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/66d39ca9e7916a5c24cd

Here is the code after I try to paste everything into the ProcessAfile method:https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a012f6d29b042b9fb818

Comment: sorry forgot to tag again @Alex

Comment: @Newuser your original code does not contain any calls to `ReadAllFilesStartingFromDirectory`. Where in your original code were you supposed to call this?

Comment: I removed it because I was just trying to use the 3 methods that you suggested, PrcocessAllFilesUnderDirectory, ProcessAfile, and Main. 
I was pretty confused, I thought I wouldn't need it anymore @Alex